# Why is my id in MVC being overwritten in the controller when trying to save a page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to save a page in MVC, and I keep getting the following error:

*System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.*

I did some research, and from what I can understand, and it all seems to point to some concurrent changes happening. However, as I was debugging my program, I noticed that a field value (an id) is changed. I suspect the reason this error is happening is because of this change. My model looks as follows:

**Model**

*ActionLog.cs*

```
namespace OneStop.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class ActionLog
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Action_ID { get; set; }
        public string Action_AddComment { get; set; }
        public string Action_Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View**

*Action.cshtml*

```
@model OneStop.Models.ActionLog
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Action_ID)

    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card-box">
                    <h4 class="mt-0 mb-3 header-title">Resolution and Status</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Action_Status">Status</label>
                        @{
                            List<SelectListItem> status = new List<SelectListItem>();
                            status.Add(new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = "OPEN",
                                Value = "Open"
                            });
                            status.Add(new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = "ONGOING",
                                Value = "Ongoing"
                            });


                     status.Add(new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = "CLOSED",
                            Value = "Closed"
                        });
                    }
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Action_Status, status, "-- Select Status --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Action_AddComment">Comments</label>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(Model => Model.Action_AddComment, new { @class = "form-control", rows = "3" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
</div>
```

}

**Controllers**

*SecurityController.cs*

```
public ActionResult Action(int id)
{
    ActionLog actionedEvents = db.ActionLog.Where(x => x.Action_ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    return View(actionedEvents);
}

//Save Actions
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Action([Bind(Include = "Id, Action_ID, Action_AddComment, Action_Status")] ActionLog actionedEvents)
{
    db.Entry(actionedEvents).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View("Index");
}
```

As I am debugging, I can go to the view that popups up in real time, and I see the value of Id will be (as an example) 20, and that Action_ID will have a value of 2987. Everything seems fine when the page loads. However, if I put a breakpoint in my save action and click submit on the form, this is when the issue occurs. Specifically, the Id no longer says 20, but rather 2987. All the other values are correct, but both Id and Action_ID have the same number of 2987.

I suspect this is why I am getting the error. Given this understanding, why is the value of Id suddenly changing to the value of Action_ID when it goes into the save part of my controller?

Comment: do you have `Id` and `Action_ID` fields on the view? they should exist for this binding to work

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, they are declared as  @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Action_ID).

Comment: Why do you have the "`Bind(Include...)`" code over there? It shouldn't be necessary. Just bind to the model directly. Does that help?

Comment: Do you have any javascript in your view? Can you tell exactly where it changes, before or after it gets to he action method?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to my problem, though I have absolutely no idea why this works. What I did was change this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Id)
```

to this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="@Model.Id">
```

and the Id became the correct value. I would love some clarification on why the Razor tag gave an incorrect value, but the regular HTML code returned the correct Id!